# why the API that generated by AM was not invoked again

Tags: wso2, api-manager, wso2-esb

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I reunzip an wso2carbon-2.0.0.zip and start this server . Then I invoked the API by postman or curl command . It all did not work.

Comment: Port 10397 is open? Can you ping and see?

Comment: But, I could see Connection time outed for that port.

Answer (score 0):

yeah,it works for the port is not open to world wide web.